# NameError: name 'collided_left' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я делаю первую игру на python 3.6 но у меня постоянно выходит ошибка. Ответе пожалуйста в чем она заключается.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Это реально сделал Амир")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, \
                highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file='background.gif')
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, \
                        image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while 1:
            if self.running == True:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)

class Coords:
    def __init__(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2

    def within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 > co2.x1 and co1.x1 < co2.x2:
            return True
        if co1.x2 > co2.x1 and co1.x2 < co2.x2:
            return True
        if co2.x1 > co1.x1 and co2.x1 < co1.x2:
            return True
        if co2.x2 > co1.x1 and co2.x2 < co1.x2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2:
            return True
        if co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2:
            return True
        if co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y2:
           return True
        if co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y2:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def collided_left (co1, co2):
        if within_y(co1, co2):
            if co1.x1 >= co2.x1 and co1.x1 <= co2.x2:
                return True
        return False

    def collided_right (co1, co2):
        if within_y(co1, co2):
            if co1.x2 >= co2.x2 and co1.x2 <= co2.x1:
                return True
        return False

    def collided_top (co1, co2):
        if within_x(co1, co2):
            if co1.y1 <= co2.y2 and co1.y1 >= co2.y1:
                return True
        return False

    def collided_bottom (y, co1, co2):
        if within_x(co1, co2):
            y_calc =co1.y2 + y
            if y_calc >= co2.y1 and y_calc <= co2.y2:
                return True
        return False

class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.endgame = False
        self.coordinates = None
    def move(self):
        pass
    def coords(self):
        return self.coordinates

class PlatformSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
                image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + width, y + height)

class StickFigureSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.images_left = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L3.gif")
        ]
        self.images_right = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R3.gif")
            ]
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(200, 470, image=self.images_left[0], anchor='nw')
        self.x = -2
        self.y = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_image_add = 1
        self.jump_count = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.coordinates = Coords()
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<space>', self.jump)


    def turn_left(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = 2

    def jump(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.y = -4
            self.jump_count = 0

    def animate(self):
        if self.x != 0 and self.y == 0:
            if time.time() - self.last_time > 0.1:
                self.last_time = time.time()
                self.current_image += self.current_image_add
                if self.current_image >= 2:
                    self.current_image_add = -1
                if self.current_image <= 0:
                    self.current_image_add = 1
        if self.x < 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                            image=self.images_left[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                            image=self.images_left[self.current_image])
        elif self.x > 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                            image=self.images_right[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, \
                                            image=self.images_right[self.current_image])

    def coords(self):
        xy = self.game.canvas.coords(self.image)
        self.coordinates.x1 = xy[0]
        self.coordinates.y1 = xy[1]
        self.coordinates.x2 = xy[0] + 27
        self.coordinates.y2 = xy[1] + 30
        return self.coordinates

    def move(self):
        self.animate()
        if self.y < 0:
            self.jump_count += 1
            if self.jump_count > 20:
                self.y = 4
        if self.y > 0:
            self.jump_count -= 1
        co = self.coords()
        left = True
        right = True
        top = True
        bottom = True
        falling = True
        if self.y > 0 and co.y2 >= self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
            bottom = False
        elif self.y < 0 and co.y1 <= 0:
            self.y = 0
            top = False
        if self.x > 0 and co.x2 >= self.game.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
            right = False
        elif self.x < 0 and co.x1 <= 0:
            self.x = 0
            left = False
        for sprite in self.game.sprites:
            if sprite == self:
                continue
            sprite_co = sprite.coords()
            if top and self.y < 0 and collided_top(co, sprite_co):
                self.y = -self.y
                top = False
            if bottom and self.y > 0 and collided_bottom(self.y, co, sprite_co):
                self.y = sprite_co.y1 - co.y2
                if self.y < 0:
                    self.y = 0
                bottom = False
                top = False
            if bottom and falling and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height and collided_bottom(1, co, sprite_co):
                falling = False
            if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                left = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
            if right and self.x > 0 and collided_right(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                right = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
        if falling and bottom and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 4
        self.game.canvas.move(self.image, self.x, self.y)

        class DoorSprite(Sprite):
            def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
                Sprite.__init__(self, game)
                self.photo_image = photo_image
                self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, \
                        image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
                self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + (width / 2), y + height)
                self.endgame = True

g = Game()
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 0, 480, 100, 10)
platform2 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 150, 440, 100, 10)
platform3 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 400, 100, 10)
platform4 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 160, 100, 10)
platform5 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 175, 350, 66, 10)
platform6 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 50, 300, 66, 10)
platform7 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 170, 120, 66, 10)
platform8 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 45, 60, 66, 10)
platform9 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 170, 250, 32, 10)
platform10 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 230, 200, 32, 10)
g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.sprites.append(platform2)
g.sprites.append(platform3)
g.sprites.append(platform10)
g.sprites.append(platform4)
g.sprites.append(platform5)
g.sprites.append(platform6)
g.sprites.append(platform7)
g.sprites.append(platform8)
g.sprites.append(platform9)
sf = StickFigureSprite(g)
g.sprites.append(sf)
g.mainloop()
```

Вот ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Александра\Desktop\stickman\stickmangame.py", line 268, in <module>
    g.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\Александра\Desktop\stickman\stickmangame.py", line 31, in mainloop
    sprite.move()
  File "C:\Users\Александра\Desktop\stickman\stickmangame.py", line 222, in move
    if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co, sprite_co):
NameError: name 'collided_left' is not defined
```

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Код неправильно используется. `collided_left` это метод класса `Coords`, а у вас он вызывается как функция и в другом классе. Если методы `Coords` вы вытащите как функции, то проблема решится

Comment: Не могли бы вы точнее описать описать проблему

Comment: Точнее будет только код показывать смотрите в ответе на `collided_left` и сравните его с вашим

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, при копипасте поехали отступы.

Код подправил:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        self.tk = Tk()
        self.tk.title("Это реально сделал Амир")
        self.tk.resizable(0, 0)
        self.tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.tk, width=500, height=500, highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.tk.update()
        self.canvas_height = 500
        self.canvas_width = 500
        self.bg = PhotoImage(file='background.gif')
        w = self.bg.width()
        h = self.bg.height()
        for x in range(0, 5):
            for y in range(0, 5):
                self.canvas.create_image(x * w, y * h, image=self.bg, anchor='nw')
        self.sprites = []
        self.running = True

    def mainloop(self):
        while True:
            if self.running:
                for sprite in self.sprites:
                    sprite.move()
            self.tk.update_idletasks()
            self.tk.update()
            time.sleep(0.01)


class Coords:
    def __init__(self, x1=0, y1=0, x2=0, y2=0):
        self.x1 = x1
        self.y1 = y1
        self.x2 = x2
        self.y2 = y2


def within_x(co1, co2):
    if co1.x1 > co2.x1 and co1.x1 < co2.x2:
        return True
    if co1.x2 > co2.x1 and co1.x2 < co2.x2:
        return True
    if co2.x1 > co1.x1 and co2.x1 < co1.x2:
        return True
    if co2.x2 > co1.x1 and co2.x2 < co1.x2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def within_y(co1, co2):
    if co1.y1 > co2.y1 and co1.y1 < co2.y2:
        return True
    if co1.y2 > co2.y1 and co1.y2 < co2.y2:
        return True
    if co2.y1 > co1.y1 and co2.y1 < co1.y2:
       return True
    if co2.y2 > co1.y1 and co2.y2 < co1.y2:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def collided_left (co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x1 >= co2.x1 and co1.x1 <= co2.x2:
            return True
    return False


def collided_right (co1, co2):
    if within_y(co1, co2):
        if co1.x2 >= co2.x2 and co1.x2 <= co2.x1:
            return True
    return False


def collided_top (co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        if co1.y1 <= co2.y2 and co1.y1 >= co2.y1:
            return True
    return False


def collided_bottom (y, co1, co2):
    if within_x(co1, co2):
        y_calc =co1.y2 + y
        if y_calc >= co2.y1 and y_calc <= co2.y2:
            return True
    return False


class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, game):
        self.game = game
        self.endgame = False
        self.coordinates = None

    def move(self):
        pass

    def coords(self):
        return self.coordinates


class PlatformSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game, photo_image, x, y, width, height):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.photo_image = photo_image
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(x, y, image=self.photo_image, anchor='nw')
        self.coordinates = Coords(x, y, x + width, y + height)


class StickFigureSprite(Sprite):
    def __init__(self, game):
        Sprite.__init__(self, game)
        self.images_left = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-L3.gif")
        ]
        self.images_right = [
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R1.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R2.gif"),
            PhotoImage(file="figure-R3.gif")
            ]
        self.image = game.canvas.create_image(200, 470, image=self.images_left[0], anchor='nw')
        self.x = -2
        self.y = 0
        self.current_image = 0
        self.current_image_add = 1
        self.jump_count = 0
        self.last_time = time.time()
        self.coordinates = Coords()
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
        game.canvas.bind_all('<space>', self.jump)

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.x = 2

    def jump(self, evt):
        if self.y == 0:
            self.y = -4
            self.jump_count = 0

    def animate(self):
        if self.x != 0 and self.y == 0:
            if time.time() - self.last_time > 0.1:
                self.last_time = time.time()
                self.current_image += self.current_image_add
                if self.current_image >= 2:
                    self.current_image_add = -1
                if self.current_image <= 0:
                    self.current_image_add = 1
        if self.x < 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_left[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_left[self.current_image])
        elif self.x > 0:
            if self.y != 0:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_right[2])
            else:
                self.game.canvas.itemconfig(self.image, image=self.images_right[self.current_image])

    def coords(self):
        xy = self.game.canvas.coords(self.image)
        self.coordinates.x1 = xy[0]
        self.coordinates.y1 = xy[1]
        self.coordinates.x2 = xy[0] + 27
        self.coordinates.y2 = xy[1] + 30
        return self.coordinates

    def move(self):
        self.animate()
        if self.y < 0:
            self.jump_count += 1
            if self.jump_count > 20:
                self.y = 4
        if self.y > 0:
            self.jump_count -= 1
        co = self.coords()
        left = True
        right = True
        top = True
        bottom = True
        falling = True
        if self.y > 0 and co.y2 >= self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 0
            bottom = False
        elif self.y < 0 and co.y1 <= 0:
            self.y = 0
            top = False
        if self.x > 0 and co.x2 >= self.game.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0
            right = False
        elif self.x < 0 and co.x1 <= 0:
            self.x = 0
            left = False
        for sprite in self.game.sprites:
            if sprite == self:
                continue
            sprite_co = sprite.coords()
            if top and self.y < 0 and collided_top(co, sprite_co):
                self.y = -self.y
                top = False
            if bottom and self.y > 0 and collided_bottom(self.y, co, sprite_co):
                self.y = sprite_co.y1 - co.y2
                if self.y < 0:
                    self.y = 0
                bottom = False
                top = False
            if bottom and falling and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height and collided_bottom(1, co, sprite_co):
                falling = False
            if left and self.x < 0 and collided_left(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                left = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
            if right and self.x > 0 and collided_right(co, sprite_co):
                self.x = 0
                right = False
                if sprite.endgame:
                    self.game.running = False
        if falling and bottom and self.y == 0 and co.y2 < self.game.canvas_height:
            self.y = 4
        self.game.canvas.move(self.image, self.x, self.y)


g = Game()
platform1 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 0, 480, 100, 10)
platform2 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 150, 440, 100, 10)
platform3 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 400, 100, 10)
platform4 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform1.gif"), 300, 160, 100, 10)
platform5 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 175, 350, 66, 10)
platform6 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 50, 300, 66, 10)
platform7 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 170, 120, 66, 10)
platform8 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform2.gif"), 45, 60, 66, 10)
platform9 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 170, 250, 32, 10)
platform10 = PlatformSprite(g, PhotoImage(file="platform3.gif"), 230, 200, 32, 10)
g.sprites.append(platform1)
g.sprites.append(platform2)
g.sprites.append(platform3)
g.sprites.append(platform10)
g.sprites.append(platform4)
g.sprites.append(platform5)
g.sprites.append(platform6)
g.sprites.append(platform7)
g.sprites.append(platform8)
g.sprites.append(platform9)
sf = StickFigureSprite(g)
g.sprites.append(sf)
g.mainloop()
```